# Dynamic maximum y-axis value on Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

With Chart.js, is there a way of setting a dynamic maximum y-axis value?

I have a chart for which the absolute maximum for a value is always 999. If the values are low (50, 100 or 200 for instance), the y-axis auto-scales (the maximum tick would be respectively 60, 110 or 210 for instance) as expected.

However, if one of the data points is 999, the y axis maximum becomes 1000. Is there any way to set 999 as the y-axis maximum *without* forcing this maximum to be 999 if I only have low values in my chart? I have tried using `max` of `suggestedMax` in the options unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to define the `data` in a variable outside of the chart configuration and then use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to define `scales.y.max`.

```
scales: {
  y: {
    max: Math.max(...data)        
  },
```

Please take a look at the following runnable code derived from the [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) and see how it works.

```js
let data = [650, 595, 999, 815, 56, 155, 440];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: data,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      lineTension: 0.1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Value'
        },
        max: Math.max(...data)        
      },
      x: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Month'
        }
      }      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta.13/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```